# matlab uicontrols

Tags: matlab, user-interface, set, figure, uicontrol

I made a gui and I have a code (thanks Amro) that shows me a gif file.

I want to show this gif file in 'hAxes' till the gui is closed (show it with the other uicontrol).

I have a folder that has 200 pictures (image1.jpg, image2.jpg... image200.jpg) and I perform some things about these images (in loading1 uicontrol).

I try something like:

```
hFigure = figure('units','pixels','position',[300 300 424 470],'menubar','none',...
'name','start processing','numbertitle','off','resize','off');        


hAxes = axes('Parent',hFigure,'Units','pixels','Position',[0 112 424 359]);
```

**%% this is what Amro made to show the gif file**

```
fname = 'loading.gif';

%# read all GIF frames**
info = imfinfo(fname, 'gif');
delay = ( info(1).DelayTime ) / 100;
[img,map] = imread(fname, 'gif', 'frames','all');
[imgH,imgW,~,numFrames] = size(img);

hImg = imshow(img(:,:,:,1), map, 'Parent',hAxes);
pause(delay)

%# loop over frames continuously
counter = 1;
while ishandle(hImg)
       %# increment counter circularly
       counter = rem(counter, numFrames) + 1;

       %# update frame
       set(hImg, 'CData',img(:,:,:,counter))

       %# update colormap
       n = max(max( img(:,:,:,counter) ));
       colormap( info(counter).ColorTable(1:n,:) )

       %# pause for the specified delay
       pause(delay)
end
```

**%% and this is the rest of my code:**

```
set(hAxes,'Visible','off', 'handlevisibility', 'off');
%% loading1 shows a data
loading1 = uicontrol('style','text','unit','pix','position',[0 72 424 40],...
'backgroundcolor','r','fontsize',20);

for i=1:200
    image = horzcat('now processing ', 'image', num2str(i), '.jpg of 200 images')
    set(loading1,'string',image);
    drawnow;
end
```

**but this code doesn't work: in this code, the gui shows the hAxes (the gif file works good), but the gui doesn't show the loading1 uicontrol. I want him to show both (hAxes and loading1)**

so I mean that I want the gui to show me the gif file and 'loading1' uicontrol both.
I think that the 'loading1' is not working because of the 'while' in the code that shows the gif file.

**this is what I got:**

[image]

**and this is what I want to get:**

[image]

and then:

[image]

and then:

[image]

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `uicontrol` does not appear because it is called after the continuous loop that handle the gif image and therefore only at the moment that you close your figure.

Using your code and creating the `uicontrol` before the loop, it seems to work as you expect it to.

```
hFigure=figure('units','pixels',...
               'position',[300 300 424 470],...
               'menubar','none',...
               'name','start processing',...
               'numbertitle','off',...
               'resize','off');        
hAxes=axes('Parent',hFigure,...
           'Units','pixels',...
           'Position',[0 112 424 359]); 
% loading1 shows a data
loading1=uicontrol('parent',hFigure,...
                   'style','text',...
                   'unit','pix',...
                   'position',[0 72 424 40],...
                   'backgroundcolor','r',...
                   'fontsize',20);
set(loading1,'string','now loading file 1 of 3');
filename='gif.gif';
% read all GIF frames
info=imfinfo(filename,'gif');
delay=(info(1).DelayTime)/100;
[img map]=imread(filename,'gif','frames','all');
[imgH imgW void numFrames]=size(img);
hImg=imshow(img(:,:,:,1),map,'Parent',hAxes);
pause(delay);
% loop over frames continuously
counter=1;
while(ishandle(hImg))
    % increment counter circularly
    counter=rem(counter,numFrames)+1;
    % update frame
    set(hImg,'CData',img(:,:,:,counter));
    % update colormap
    n=max(max(img(:,:,:,counter)));
    colormap(info(counter).ColorTable(1:n,:));
    % pause for the specified delay
    pause(delay);
end
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work. I think it doesn't work because it goes to infinity loop.
by the way you suggested, it shows the other uicontrol, but doesn't run the code after the loop of while(ishandle(hImg))..

Comment: What does not work exactly? You mentionned in your question that you wanted the GUI to show the gif image and the uicontrol text, and that is what this code does on my computer. What other code do you want it to run? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: the code is so long, so I put just the relevant code. I am trying tight now to explain more in my topic.